# ConfigurationSection won't convert to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, configuration, config

I have this `Q1.config` file in my Console Application (.NET 4.5.2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="globalKey" value="globalValue" />
    </appSettings>

    <configSections>
        <section name="validations" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </configSections>

    <validations>
        <add key="validationKey" value="validationValue"/>
    </validations>
</configuration>
```

I'm reading it like this

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "Q1.config" };
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationSection validationSettings = config.GetSection("validations");
```

This works fine:

```
string globalValue = config.AppSettings.Settings["globalKey"].Value;
```

But how do I get my "validationKey"? I tried these but they don't work:

```
validationSettings["validationKey"]
validationSettings.Settings["validationKey"]
(config.GetSection("validations") as NameValueCollection)["validationKey"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

Your XML configuration

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   <section name="validations" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection" />
  </configSections>
 <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
 </startup>
 <appSettings>
   <add key="globalKey" value="globalValue" />
 </appSettings>
 <validations>
   <add key="validationKey" value="validationValue"/>
 </validations>
</configuration>
```

And you can get these values in C# using

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "Q1.config" };

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

NameValueCollection validationSettings = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("validations");

string globalValue = validationSettings[0];
```

I've used an index here `validationSettings[0]` to access the value. You can use your key to get the value

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible this code is outdated? when I use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` I only get null, to get the section I have to use the `config` object returned by `OpenMappedExeConfiguration`. However, GetSection in config isn't of type `object` as in ConfigurationManager, but `DefaultSection` from which I can't read the key value pairs, nor can I cast it to `NameValueCollection`

Comment: @PedroC88 Could be very well outdated. Let me know which framework and application you're trying to build. I'll come up with the latest code on how to read the config values.

Comment: I already another answer with the solution that worked for me based on what you sent. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

With the answer from @Karthik I ran into an issue... if I use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` I only get null. To get the section I have to use the config object returned by `OpenMappedExeConfiguration`. However, GetSection() in config isn't of type `object` as in ConfigurationManager, but `DefaultSection` from which I can't read the key value pairs, nor can I cast it to `NameValueCollection`. Browsing on the web I found [this article](https://en.it1352.com/article/b9184ea78d4f44669991511176ae50cb.html) with a solution that worked for me.

Basically extract the XML from the section and parse it manually with an XmlDoc.

```
public static NameValueCollection GetSectionSettings(string sectionToRead, string configPath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(configPath)) { throw new ArgumentException($"File not found: {configPath}", nameof(configPath)); }

    var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = configPath };
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    string settingsXml = config.GetSection(sectionToRead).SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
    XmlDocument settingsXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    settingsXmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(settingsXml));
    NameValueSectionHandler handler = new NameValueSectionHandler();

    return handler.Create(null, null, settingsXmlDoc.DocumentElement) as NameValueCollection;
}
```